# How to force QFileDialog.getOpenFileName to read file only in a specific folder

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, pyqt

With Python and PyQT, is possible to force QFileDialog.getOpenFileName() to show and select file only in a specific folder including subfolders?

Alternatively: what is the most elegant way in Python and PyQT to forcing the user to select a file in a specific folder and subfolders?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need to force the user to only select files from one folder and not another? This should be the user's choice after all. If you want to make sure your program does not process unsupported files, you can use the returned filename to check if it makes sense to proceed or repromt the user to select another file.

Comment: "Why would you need to force the user to only select files from one folder and not another?" 
Wait. I turn the question to the customer... :-)